# How to implement a "In Progress" animation in Swing?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am working on an application that executes some functions that run for long. To let the user aware that the processing is taking place, I needed a label that can display some label that can represent that. So, I created a small widget for such a label.

The program below runs find and I get the output as I wanted.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


/**
 * This is an extension to a JLabel that can be used to display an ongoing progress.
 * @author Ankit Gupta
 */
public class ProgressLabel extends JLabel {

    /**
     * The prefix label to which periods are added.
     */
    private String startLabel;
    /**
     * The label to display end of an operation.
     */
    private String endLabel;

    /**
     * Flag to indicate whether the animation is running or not.
     */
    private boolean running = false;
    //list to hold intermediate labels
    List<String> intermediateLabels;

    public ProgressLabel(String slbl, String elbl) {
        this.startLabel = slbl;
        this.endLabel = elbl;
        //initialize all the labels to be used once as creating them again and again is expensive
        intermediateLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
        intermediateLabels.add(startLabel+".");
        intermediateLabels.add(startLabel+"..");
        intermediateLabels.add(startLabel+"...");
        intermediateLabels.add(startLabel+"....");
    }

    public void done(){
        running = false;
    }

    public void start(){
        running = true;
        new LabelUpdateThread().start();
    }

    private class LabelUpdateThread extends Thread{
        int i;

        public LabelUpdateThread(){
            i=0;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(running){
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setText(intermediateLabels.get((i++)%3));
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
            setText(endLabel);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws InterruptedException{
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing ProgressLabel");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        ProgressLabel progressLabel = new CZProgressLabel("Searching", "Done");
        panel.add(progressLabel);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        frame.pack();
        progressLabel.start();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } 
        });
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        progressLabel.done();
    }
}
```

However, when I tried to include this in the application, it did not work as expected. I created a small panel with a button and in the `actionPerfomed()` code for the button I used the `ProgressLabel`'s **start()** and **done()** methods as before but this time, the label just did not update to *Done* until the length process finished. Here is another piece of code using the `ProgressLabel` with `actionPerformed()` :

```
public class SearchPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextArea queryBox;
    private JButton searchBtn;
    private ProgressLabel progressLabel;
    private JSeparator queryAreaSeparator;

    public SearchPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //First Row
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        queryBox = new JTextArea();
        queryBox.setRows(25);
        queryBox.setColumns(25);
        this.add(queryBox, gbc);


        //Second Row
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        progressLabel = new ProgressLabel("Searching", "Done");
        this.add(progressLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        searchBtn = new JButton("Search");
        this.add(searchBtn, gbc);
        searchBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                progressLabel.start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
                }
                //the above sleep() call will be replace by some time-consuming process. It is there just for testing now

                progressLabel.done();
            }
        });


        gbc.gridx = 0;
    }

    /**
     * function to test CZSemanticSearchLabel
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        CZSemanticSearchPanel panel = new CZSemanticSearchPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        frame.dispose();


        final JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Testing ProgressLabel");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        CZProgressLabel progressLabel = new CZProgressLabel("Searching", "Done");
        panel1.add(progressLabel);
        frame1.add(panel1);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame1.pack();
        progressLabel.start();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        progressLabel.done();
    }
}
```

I believe that I have screwed something with Swing's Event dispatch model. But, I cannot figure what? Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about your actual code, but your sample code is flawed...

In your `ActionListener` you are doing this...

```
progressLabel.start();
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
}
//the above sleep() call will be replace by some time-consuming process. It is there just for testing now

progressLabel.done();
```

This will **STOP** the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), preventing any repaint requests from the been handled (ie no screen updates) for 10 seconds...this will also make your application look like it's "hung".

I updated you `ActionListener` to read like this (note I added a `isRunning` method which returns the `running` member from the label)

```
if (progressLabel.isRunning()) {
    progressLabel.done();
} else {
    progressLabel.start();
}
```

And it works fine.

You might like to read through [Currency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for some more ideas.

Also, as already suggested, SwingWorker may be a better approach

Comment: Have a read about the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), this is a VERY important concept in Swing. Firstly, you should only ever update UI components from the EDT. Secondly, you should never do ANYTHING that might block it - this will cause your application to appear hung.

Comment: [JProgressBar.setIndeteminate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate(boolean)) in particular ;)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of implementing this yourself with threading, you can use [SwingWorker: Simple Background Tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) that is made for such things, and the linked example is very similar to your problem.

Your `start()` doesn't execute your `LabelUpdateThread().run()` but your `LabelUpdateThread().start()`.

Comment: But, there is not `LabelUpdateThread.start()`! Did I misundertand u? BTW Thanks for the SwingWorker link. However, its just one of those things that I want to do from scratch (me being a newbie to Swing development - trying to get a learning experience from this excercise). Thanks

Comment: I admire your desire to do it from scratch - this is always a good idea.  Swingworker does greatly simplify many, many scenarios (and I do encourage you to use it), but writing it on your own is a great first step to understanding how this all works. Here's the rule: Do not perform ANY time consuming task on the EDT (anything that would take more than a few 10's of milliseconds). Get it off the EDT as fast as you can (the simple way to do this is to spawn a new thread - the right way to do it is to use a thread pool - ExecutorService is a huge help for that)