# How to move a icon in a panel

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to move a JLabel with image in a `JPanel` with a single thread.

```
private void moveBaloon(JLabel Baloon){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Bowandarrow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Point point= Baloon.getLocation();
        Baloon.setLocation(point.x, point.y-4);

    }
}
```

After 5 seconds the balloon is moved to another position but it is not visually moving. What can I do to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a "In Progress" animation in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206998/how-to-implement-a-in-progress-animation-in-swing)

Answer (score 0):

You are causing the EDT to sleep, which means the GUI can't repaint itself until the entire animation is finished.

Instead you should be using a Swing Timer to fire an event every 500ms to move the label. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

Also, you can search the forum to find lots of examples. "animation" "timer" would probably be good keywords.